# Routing issue with Linux VM as Wireguard Router

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, wireguard

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 VM that i want to act as a Wireguard "Router" for devices on the LAN. That is - devices at home should be able to set the VM as default gateway and browse the internet through the VPN. My home LAN is 10.0.0.0/22 and the VM is 10.0.3.1. Wireguard is already set up in client mode and works, if i browse to whatismyip.com with links2 on the VM, i get the correct IP of the VPN endpoint. I have also enabled ipv4 forwarding in the VM.

However, if i set the VM as default gateway on another box in the house, it doesn't work. I'm able to ping the VM from that box, so i'm assuming its some kind of routing issue in the VM?

Edit: `ip route` reports the following, yet still links2 uses the VPN. The route table suggests the default route is via my home LAN, yet still links2 connects via VPN. How? And is a missing route the reason i cannot set the VM as gateway?

```
% ip route                                                                                         
~ wireguard-client
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp src 10.0.3.1 metric 100 
10.0.0.0/22 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.1 metric 100 
10.0.0.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.3.1 metric 100 
10.0.0.2 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.3.1 metric 100
```

`ip a`

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:f9:11:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.3.1/22 metric 100 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
   valid_lft 85716sec preferred_lft 85716sec
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fef9:1161/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/none 
inet 10.49.0.2/32 scope global wg0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`traceroute 1.1.1.1`

```
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.49.0.1 (10.49.0.1)  148.011 ms  148.012 ms  147.992 ms <- VPN!
 2  * * *
```

How come traceroute goes via vpn when deafult route is via 10.0.0.1?!

Comment: what exactly does not work? are you still getting the IP from before or do you have no internet access at all?

Comment: Sorry, no internet access at all.

Comment: Didn't you forget to just enable IP forwarding in the VM? That is, by running `echo net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 >> /etc/sysctl.d/ip_forward.conf` or similar. Also, does the remote WireGuard server have the route to your local network through the tunnel, or does your VM do NAT for local addresses (`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE` or similar)?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Forwarding is on as stated in post and remote side is ok since it works in a pfSense VM, i just prefer to use a lighter VM with WG only. The only thing im unsure about is the last iptables thing, how do i check that? Its a vanilla Ubuntu + Wireguard.

Answer (score 0):

It's the routing issue. You can do one of the following:

1. On the *remote WG node* (`10.49.0.1`) add a route towards LAN via other WireGuard end (`10.0.0.0/22 via 10.49.0.2`). Also it needs to be set to allow the whole LAN over the WireGuard (e.g. this peer must have `AllowedIPs = 10.49.0.2/32, 10.0.0.0/22`) and permit to NAT this whole range.
2. On the *local WG node* (`10.49.0.2`) add the NAT `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE`. It will map all the LAN requests to this node's WG IP, therefore the remote node will not know that there is a whole LAN behind its peer.

The first way is overall cleaner, since all the complexity is being kept on the VPN gateway, the remote, and there is only one NAT in the system; the local node will only be doing tunelling and routing. However, the second way might appear easier to do, because it has less to consider.

To check (dump) the current firewall configuration you might just run `iptables-save` and inspect the output.

And, lastly. `tcpdump` is your friend in solving networking problems. If you can't figure out why something works, start capturing traffic on relevant interfaces and see if it is as expected. For example, you may see if LANs traffic appears on the remote WG node; I suspect currently it isn't. Or you may check if it is being translated as expected.

Comment: So the reason it works via pfSense is probably because it adds the masqureading for me then. Ill try the first option - seems like a better solution. Thanks.